# How to Push changes from SVN server to Remote web server

Tags: svn, repository-pattern, push

**The Problem**

I need to push changes from an SVN server to a remote web server whenever a developer commits code.  I would like to do this efficiently.  Therefore, I'd like to only push changes to the remote server and not the whole repository.

**The Current Situation**

Currently, the remote server calls an update every five minutes.  However, I would rather the traffic be inbound to the webserver instead of outbound. The svn server is on a Windows 2003 box.  The webserver is an OpenSUSE 11.4 box.

**Previous SO Searches**

I've search SO for this question, but it seems you guys love git and most questions deal with that software.

Thanks SO in advance.  You guys are great.

Comment: Can you trigger the update by SSHing into your SUSE box? If so, you can set up a post-commit hook on your SVN server to do this. Hopefully someone can fill in the details as an answer!

Comment: When you say push the changes to a remote web server, in what format are you pushing them.  Are you trying to mirror the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on Rup's comment (since he asked!).

It sounds like your remote server (let's call it server B) has a working copy of a section of the repository. You want your repository located on another server (server A) to trigger an `svn update` command on server B.

There are several ways of doing this (like having a checked out working copy on server A with an rsync of that working copy pushed to server B, allowing you to also mask the .svn directories). But, like Rup says, the easiest way is to set up a simple post-commit hook to SSH into server B and do an update. On server A (assuming you have authorized_keys set up between server A and B):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh serverB 'svn update /path/to/working/copy' > /dev/null
```

Comment: How do you enter password for ssh and for svn in this approach?

Comment: You have to set up an authorized_keys file on the remote server (in my example, serverB). That will allow server A to connect to server B without having to type in a password.